# Div moving when the browser is risizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive

I have a code like this 69authentic.com/fancy/hero.html my `.hero-panel__desc` is move up when the browser is risizing. How to prevent that from happening?

EDIT:

sorry i didn't provide the code before

```css
.desc__contact {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -250px;
  left: -30px;
}

.desc__contact ul li {
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style: none;
}

.home-panel {
  z-index: 0;
  height: 1920px;
  background: white;
  transform: skew(0deg, -65deg) translateY(-1990px);
}

.logo {
  z-index: 20;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 80px;
}

.hero-panel__desc {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(30% - 60px);
  left: 65px;
  padding: 10px;
  transform: skew(0deg, 65deg) translateY(1000px);
}

.icons {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background:gray;height:100vh;overflow:hidden;" class="ultimate-hero">
  <div style="z-index:10;position:absolute;overflow:hidden;" class="home-panel">
    <div class="hero-panel__desc">
      <div class="desc__about">
        <p>
          <b>Sixtynine authentic</b> merupakan sebuah brand sport apparel yang lahir dari kearifan lokal untuk menghasilkan produk yang berkualitas. Kami hadir untuk mewujudkan impian jersey anda dengan model yang di inginkan dengan kualitas terbaik dan
          harga terjangkau. Check <a href="#">how to order</a>.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="desc__contact">
        <ul>
          <li>
            Jl. Solontongan No. 20C Buahbatu, Bandung
          </li>
          <li>
            +62877 6996 6969
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="icons">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or you can see it here https://jsfiddle.net/atmocode/Lkjdsp96/ please expand the viewport (don't know what it's called) to see what i mean.

Comment: Please include your code in your question and let us see if what you've got so far.

Comment: Please share your code (`HTML`, `CSS` and `JavaScript`)

Comment: I just edited it

Comment: You've a javascript code run on window resive
"  $('.hero-panel__desc').css({
      'transform': 'skew(0deg,65deg) translateY('+width/2+'px)',
  });"
This code is resposible for moving up

Comment: yeah i know that, even though if i remove that code i still get the same result, the div is still moving up